Gnome Files (Nautilus) How to set maximum file size to get a thumbnail?
Gnome Files browser shows thumbnails for files up to certain size. How can I change that size?
I have found a pull request that removed it from the preferences, and from there, I found that I can change it using dconf-editor under org.gnome.nautilus/thumbnail-limit.
But it doesn't seem to work - files are still not being thumbnailed.

What else can block it?
Can I see a log of the thumbnails creation process somehow?

